# Linux: Same static IP configured for all NICs

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu-14.04, nic, ip-address

I am shipping some servers out to remote colo sites. I want to configure them so at the other end any port can be lit-up and the boxes will be good to go.

I had originally been planning on bonding the interfaces together to accomplish this, but due to a driver issue, I cannot do this.

If I create two duplicate static configurations for two interfaces (say p1p1 and p1p2) in /etc/network/interfaces will the system be confused on which to route too (even if only one interface is up)?

Note: OS is Ubuntu 14.0.2 LTS

Comment: Configuring same static IP address for multiple interfaces on a host is not a problem. Routing might be an issue, but it shouldn't be hard for you to test. If you are sure that only one of the interfaces is going to get connected, you could configure all the interfaces in a bridge. But with bridging it is going to break badly if multiple interfaces are then actually hooked up to the switch (unless loop detection is in place to stop the breakage).